# P0102 code on highlander 2014 (mass air flow sensor) after damaging oxygen sensor wire

Tags: toyota, highlander

I have the check engine light on. Scanner shows P0102 (Mass or Volume Air Flow A Circuit Low).

No noticeable issue with performance, other than exhaust smells rich.

I have run over a spool of wire on a highway that got wrapped on the drive shaft, it also wrapped around the oxygen sensor (downstream from the catalytic converter). That's when the light came on. The wires on the oxygen sensor got damaged, but I don't think they were severed. Could have been shorted though. I have repaired oxygen sensor wires but mass air flow won't go away.

I checked the mass air flow sensor it is clean. Disconnecting the mass air flow sensor adds P0113 (intake air temperature) code.

Disconnecting the MAF sensor while engine is running does nothing.

The wires are sealed so I can't easily connect meter/scope to them without disconnecting the sensor. But when it is disconnected pink wire has 4.99V.

Do I start with replacing the mass air flow sensor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: replaced a MAF sensor. Did reset - same thing. Next step - harness continuity test, where can I get a wiring diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fuse. To my dismay, even though the thought occurred to me - I dismissed it because I thought that MAF would be on a separate fuse.